# Google Cloud Dataprep - ETL capabilities

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I know that Dataprep isn't out yet but I'm very curious to know if it would be possible to perform ETL transformations using Dataprep?

Is it going to be a replacement to Dataflow?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Dataprep is basically UI which spins up a Dataflow job so expect similar ETL capabilities and performance. As with every UI it is likely that actually writing your Dataflow pipeline in code will give you more control, on the other hand Dataprep will make it more accessible.

To get more information have a look at the [product page](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/) and perhaps some [videos from Next](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5PJfSjX5ws).